# Why doesn't LD_LIBRARY_PATH has any effect?

Tags: filesystem, compiling, dynamic-linking, clang

./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

even though:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/exe/libcxx/lib:/home/exe/llvm/lib:/usr/local/lib
$ ls /usr/local/lib
libc++.so  libc++.so.1  libc++.so.1.0  python2.7  python3.2
```

I even copied it next to the executable, still no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might need to run `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` to update the dynamic linker cache. Otherwise I think the system doesn't know which libraries are available from that directory. See `man ldconfig` for more info.

Comment: It works. Do I have to repeat it after every reboot?

Comment: No, it should update `/etc/ld.so.cache` permanently. You should only need to re-run if you add or remove libraries in that directory again (normally `apt-get` handles this step for you for packaged libraries under `/usr`).

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer turns out to be that you should do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ..`
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export